# How can I run `scalafmt` on a specific file?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalafmt

I know if I do `sbt scalafmt` it will run it on the entire project. How can I do this for a specific file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sbt-scalafmt provides a `scalafmtOnly` task for this. It's documented at https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#task-keys , where we see:

> `scalafmtOnly <file>...`: Format specified files listed

You could also, outside of sbt, use the `scalafmt` command, which is installable via Coursier.

Scalafmt can be now be launched via `scala-cli`, so you can also:

> `scala-cli format <file>...`